# Load HTML code into a Windows Forms Tooltip using ToolStripControlHost

Tags: c#

I am going to display tooltip with multicolor text.

I am trying to load html code in tooltip.

I am using below code to load html code in tooltip.

But I dont know how to change tooltip text at runtime and calculate the webbrowser size.

For example in this sample when clicking button2 I want to change the tooltip text.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // the shown webbrowser
        private WebBrowser webBrowser1;
        private WebBroswerToolTip2 toolTip;
        // the webbrowser that get the size
        private WebBrowser webBrowser2;
        Size BodySize;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser2 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted;
            this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
        }

        private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle Rect = this.webBrowser2.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle;
            BodySize = new Size(Rect.Width, Rect.Height);
        }

        string documenttext = "<html><body>" +
                       // "<h1><b>This is de title of the tooltip text</b></h1>" +
                        "<p>Display sample text <u>here</u>.</p>" +
                        "</body></html>";

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = documenttext;
            webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            webBrowser1.Size = BodySize;
            toolTip = new WebBroswerToolTip2(webBrowser1);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser2.DocumentText = documenttext;
            webBrowser2.Update();
        }

        private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = new Point();
            point.X = button1.Location.X + button1.Width / 2;
            point.Y = button1.Location.Y + button1.Height;
            //toolTip.Show(webBrowser1, point);
            toolTip.Show(webBrowser1, MousePosition);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser2.DocumentText = "<html><body>" +
                       "<p>ggjh</u>.</p>" +
                       "</body></html>";
            webBrowser2.Update();

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body>" +
                       "<p>ggjh</u>.</p>" +
                       "</body></html>";
            webBrowser1.Update();

        }

        private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip.Dispose();
            webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = documenttext;
            webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            webBrowser1.Size = BodySize;
            toolTip = new WebBroswerToolTip2(webBrowser1);
        }
    }


    class WebBroswerToolTip2 : ToolStripDropDown
    {
        public Control ctl;
        public WebBroswerToolTip2(Control aControl)
            : base()
        {
            this.ctl = aControl;
            Initialize();
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.AutoSize = false;
            ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(this.ctl);
            this.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            this.Padding = Padding.Empty;
            host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
            host.AutoSize = false;
            host.Size = ctl.Size;
            this.Size = ctl.Size;
            this.Items.Add(host);
        }
    }
```